# I'm trying to find which letters I've been used from inserted

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a =input("Write a sentence or phrase :")
symbol = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for key in symbol:
    print(key, a.count(key))
```

I tried to count every letter Capital,small letters include and everybody already understood what I meant if I need to be more clear how can I count capital letters too .Thanks everyone for the Answer.I've solved !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lower everything from your input first:

```
initialInput = input("Write a sentence or phrase :")
lowerInput = initialInput.lower()
symbol = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for key in symbol:
    print(key, lowerInput.count(key))
```

Comment: that's better, to use `lower()` initially instead of loop.

Comment: Note that you could also use `input("Whatever")` directly after appending a `.lower()`at the end but it could lead to confusion later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `lower()` method on the string input:

```
for key in symbol:
   print (key, a.lower().count(key))
```

Comment: Keys are already lowercase

Comment: It should be `a` not `key` for lower()

Comment: @cricket_007 please see my recent edit.

Comment: You could also just lower immediately on the input rather than doing it repeatedly in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Just use `a.lower()` when taking input, and count in your loop.

```
a =input("Write a sentence or phrase :").lower()
symbol = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for key in symbol:
    print(key, a.count(key))
```

Or use `Counter`, then you don't need `symbol` to compare.

```
from collections import Counter 
a =input("Write a sentence or phrase :").lower()
print(Counter(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter 
counts = Counter("Hello, world!")
for k, v in counts.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it separate `h` and `H` in the final count?

Comment: Based on the question, I'd say that's what's wanted